# ProFTPd: Files and Directories of users group readable?

Tags: ftp, file-permissions, proftpd

I have set proftpd users in mysql database using "proftpd administrator". Users home directories follow the rule `/backup/agency_name/user1`, `/backup/agency_name/user2`, ..., `/backup/agency_name/userN`.

Now I want to set a new user (The chief of the agency) so that he can only read/download everything in `/backup/agency_name/` saved by users of his agency. I don't know if users home directories are well named the way I did.

Any suggestion please? and what proftpd directives to use?

Thanks